# Regularity of KAK decomposition

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider $G/K$ a symmetric space of compact type. We have $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}+\mathfrak{m}$. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a maximal abelian subspace of $\mathfrak{m}$. Then we have a root system $\Sigma$ and we chose positive roots $\Sigma^+$. If we denote $$\mathfrak{a}_r=\left\lbrace H\in \mathfrak{a}\vert \forall \lambda\in \Sigma,\lambda(H)\not\in i\pi\mathbb{Z}\right\rbrace,$$an $Q$ the connected component of $\mathfrak{a}_r$ containend in the Weyl chamber associated to the choice of positive roots and containing $0$ in its closure.

In Helgason, *Differential Geometry, Lie Groups and Symmetric Spaces*, Theorem 8.6 p.323, it is shown that for any $g\in G$, there are $k_1,k_2\in G$ and a unique $H\in \overline{Q}$ such that $g=k_1\exp(H)k_2$.

My question is, is the map $g\mapsto H(g)$ smooth ? And $k_i$ are not unique, but is there a choice such that $g\mapsto k_i(g)$ is also smooth ?

Comment: Hint: Try the $SL(2,R)$ case.

Comment: I think that for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, if $d$ is the hyperbolic metric on the upper half plane, we have $H(g)=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(d(i,g(i))\right)\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\-1&0\end{pmatrix}$ so $H$ will be smooth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Lie subgroup $D_+$ of $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$ consisting of diagonal matrices with positive diagonal entries, $A=diag(a, a^{-1}), a>0$. Then
$$
H(A)= \log(a),\ a\ge 1,$$
$$
H(A)=\log(a^{-1})= -\log(a),\ 0< a\le 1
$$
(up to a normalizing multiplicative factor). In other words, $H(A)=|\log(a)|$.

I will leave it to you to verify that this function is not even differentiable at $a=1$, let alone smooth. Since $D_+$ is a smooth submanifold of  $SL(2, {\mathbb R})$, it follows that $H: SL(2, {\mathbb R})\to {\mathfrak a}^+=\bar{Q}$ is not smooth.

The situation will be similar for higher rank Lie groups: The Cartan projection $H$ will not be smooth over the boundary of ${\mathfrak a}^+$ (but smooth over ${\mathfrak a}^+_r$).

Comment: Thank you, I see where the problem is. In your last statement, you say that $H$ will be smooth on the interior and that the probleme lies at the boundary. Actually, I know that the boundary is a problem, so I should have seen that. But then if I consider $G_1=K\exp(Q)K$ which is an open subset of $G$ where we kept only elements such that $H(g)$ are in the interior $Q$ and removed elements where $H(g)$ is in the boundary $\overline{Q}\setminus Q$. Then, is $H$ smooth on $G_1$ or are there other issues ?

Comment: @Sora Yes, $H$ is smooth on $G_1$. The key is that this is essentially a quotient map $G_1\to Q$ by a **free** action of a compact Lie group, therefore, a smooth fiber bundle.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I have two questions left : are $k_1,k_2$ also smooth on $G_1$ ? And do you know if there is a reference for this (or those) results ?

Comment: @Sora: they can be chosen to be smooth. This is just a general nonsense about fiber bundles over a base which is an open convex subset of an affine space.